# Keeping the input request as JSON

Tags: json, laravel, input

My application need to post data to external endpoint and getting the response. But that external endpoint disable cross origin so I can't make the request directly from front-end JS but have to make it from the back-end laravel.

My question is if I post the JSON body data from my JS front-end to my back-end laravel, How to keep it as JSON? So the laravel can POST that JSON data to external endpoint with Guzzle.

Comment: You don't really need to preserve the JSON data as a string. If you do `$client->request("POST", "endpoint", [ "json" => request()->json() ]);` it should be sent correctly

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. but i've tried this. but this can't work because request()->json() data type is object and json_encode can't process this, the result of json_encode(request()->json()) will be only empty string. I think json_encode can only process an array.

Comment: how about `request()->json()->all()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to preserve the JSON data as a string. If you do `$client->request("POST", "endpoint", [ "json" => request()->json()->all() ]);` it should be sent correctly. It is an easy and Effective way.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. but i've tried this. but this can't work because request()->json() data type is object and json_encode can't process this, the result of json_encode(request()->json()) will be only empty string. I think json_encode can only process an array.

Comment: then instead of `json()` use `toArray()` method.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it has been solved with $request->json()->all();